# Cannot Change Linux Lite Screen Resolution in Hyper-V

Tags: resolution, hyper-v

I have been unable to change the screen resolution for a Linux Lite 6.x VM running in Hyper-V. I edited the `/etc/default/grub` file to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to add `video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080` (followed by `sudo update-grub`, shutting down both the VM and Hyper-V before restarting), but it had no effect.

I also tried installing linux-image-extras with the hyperv-drivers (`sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual`), followed by a reboot, with no effect.

I realize this is a common issue; I've seen lots of people asking about it. The one thing that's different for me is that I also have an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS VM and a Zorin OS Lite VM (the latter of which is xfce-based, just like Linux Lite). I can resize the display on both of those instances; only Linux Lite is not resizable. As far as I know, I installed all the VM's following the same procedure with the same settings (e.g., Guest Services is activated in all three machines).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up addressing the issue, successfully, by following the [instructions on this web site](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session/).

As described in the link, after installing the OS in Hyper-V, here are the terminal commands I followed:

`$ cd ~/Downloads/`

`$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hinara/linux-vm-tools/ubuntu20-04/ubuntu/20.04/install.sh`

I made the downloaded file executable and ran the script:

`$ sudo chmod +x install.sh`

`$ sudo /.install.sh`

I then rebooted and repeated the procedure:

`$ reboot`

`$ cd ~/Downloads/`

`$ sudo ./install.sh`

The directions then instruct users to enable enhanced session mode in Hyper-V, but it was already enabled for me. I did, though, start PowerShell (as administrator) and executed:

`Set-VM -VMName "Linux Lite 6" -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket`
(of course, put your own VM's OS name inside the quotes)

I restarted everything, and was good to go!